# Geocoder Rails: Using multiple APIs for different tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rubygems

I am using the Geocoder gem for Rails, which is brilliantly simple and easy to implement.

I am using the gem on a website where users search for jobs near a location, and for this I am using the Bing API in the background to process the geocoding requests.

I am finding that the quality of the results from using the Bing API are very poor. I get very patchy results and this leaves me with a bunch of entries without any geocoding data whatsoever.

So, I have an idea for a solution, but I am unsure how precisely I can implement this...

I want to be able to use the Google API to power the initial geocoding process - i.e, when an object is geocoded, I want the Google API to handle this process, as it is far more reliable than the Bing offering.

I then want to be able to continue using the Bing API for any search related geocoding queries: `Object.near(whatever)` for example.

I know that I can configure multiple services with geocoder, however I am unsure how I explicitly use one service for a specific purpose. Has anybody else got any experience of doing this with geocoder?

Answer (score 0):

Rather late, but if anybody is looking for the answer, you pass the service as a :lookup value, eg.

`Geocoder.search("City Ground, Nottingham, UK", :lookup => :google)`